# ActiveRecord include with order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models:

```
 class FirstModel < AR::B
   belongs_to :second_model
 end

 class SecondModel < AR::B
   #name
   has_many :first_model
 end
```

I have code:

```
 @a = FirstModel.where(#some query)
 @a.include([:second_model])
```

How i can include SecondModel with order by name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably asking for `order` option in has_many method. eg.:

`has_many :first_models, order: 'name'`

But your code snippet is not perfect, because `FirstModel` has only one `SecondModel` (belongs to) and you are probably asking for `SecondModel.where(...).include(:first_models)`.